Verify whether new particles overlap with other particles
I am trying to generate non-overlapping particles in n-dimensional space.
Currently, I generate a new position and check whether it overlaps with existing particles. This process takes a lot of time because I need to compute distances N times.
I want to use a KD-tree to speed up the process of checking whether new particles overlap with existing ones. However, I am unsure how to start with this in Python. Could you please provide some advice?

Assuming you have main data and new data
mainData = existing_Points
newData = generated_Points
tolarance = 1 #Change to 0 if only checking the points
tree = KDTree(mainData)
indices = tree.query_ball_point(newData, tolerance)
unique_indices = np.unique(np.concatenate(indices))
if len(unique_indices) == 0:
   print("No intersection found")
else:
   print("intersection found")

Is this what you need?
